# in batch apex class i want multiply of two fields?

Tags: apex, soql, batch

In my bath apex class here is a `list<Aggrgateresut>` in that there is only one sum of `Relative_Date_Calculated__c`, but I want sum of 
`Relative_Date_Calculated__c` and `transctional_Amount__c`.

```
   // Start Meth
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    // Execute Logic
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> contacts){

        // Set TriggerUtility.isRewardsBatchProcess = true to prevent Contact triggers from there execution.
        TriggerUtility.isRewardsBatchProcessing = true;

        // Logic to be Executed batch wise 
        Map<String, Contact> contactsMap = new Map<String, Contact>();

        for(Contact conRec : contacts){
            initalizeAllFields(conRec);
            contactsMap.put(conRec.Id, conRec);
        }  

        Set<String> brandNameSet = new Set<String>{'AOS', 'State', 'American', 'Takagi'};
        Set<String> reportingGroupSet = new Set<String>{'standard gas & electric', 'heat pump', 'high efficiency gas', 'tankless', 'solar', 'commercial',  'bonus'};

        // Aggregate Query to collect Sum of all Combinations of Brand Name and Reporting Groups.           
        List<AggregateResult> arrAllDaysCRsResult = [SELECT Sum(Relative_Date_Calculated__c) totalRewards, Brand_Name__c, Reporting_Group__c, Contractor__c FROM Contractor_Rewards__c 
                                            WHERE Brand_Name_Calculated__c in:brandNameSet AND Contractor__c in:contactsMap.keyset() // AND Reporting_Group__c in:reportingGroupSet
                                            group by Brand_Name__c, Reporting_Group__c, Contractor__c ];  

 for(AggregateResult arrResult: arrAllDaysCRsResult){

            // Populate State fields
            if((arrResult.get('Brand_Name__c')+'').toUpperCase().contains('STATE') && contactsMap.get((arrResult.get('Contractor__c')+'')) != null 
                                                                                   && reportingGroupSet.contains((arrResult.get('Reporting_Group__c')+'').toLowerCase())){
                populateContactStateFields(contactsMap.get((arrResult.get('Contractor__c')+'')), arrResult);
            }

 private void populateContactAmericanFields(Contact conRecord, AggregateResult arrResult){

        // American - Standard Gas & Electric
        if(((arrResult.get('Reporting_Group__c')+'').toLowerCase()).equals('standard gas & electric') ){ 
            conRecord.American_Standard_Tank_ranking_points__c = (Decimal)arrResult.get('totalRewards');
        }
```

Comment: I don't see anyplace in your code that shows the field `transctional_Amount__c` nor do I see anything that tells us what type field `Relative_Date_Calculated__c` is. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't help you if you don't take the time to tell us where you're stuck and what kind of fields these are.  Why not put your values in maps, do the multiplication and the results in another map?

Comment: Relative_Date_Calculated__c is formula field and i want this formula field to multiply with transctional_Amount__c,but i am not getting how to do this?